# How to make an animation on an ImageView in android?

Tags: android-animation

I have problem with my code of making a rotation animation on an ImageView. My ImageView is in service not in an activity.

```
ImageView myImage = new ImageView(this);
                final Animation myRotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.rotator);
                myImage.startAnimation(myRotation);
```

My XML rotation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="4000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="90"
    android:toYScale="0.0" />
```

I have tried this successfully if the ImageView looks like:

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

Instead of: `ImageView myImage = new ImageView(this);`

However, I have to choice to initialize `myImage = new ImageView(this);`

So, is there any trick to make my ImageView rotatable?

Comment: Without animation can you see your ImageView myImage = new ImageView(this);?

Comment: Yes. I can see it. Actually, I am making a floating image on the screen by a service.

Comment: How about making your view like following: ImageView myImage = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());?

Comment: It still persists in not working. I have no idea about this.

Comment: The only difference I notice is 2 different context you are using. One is application context other is your activity context. How about constructing animation following: final Animation myRotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotator); and ImageView myImage = new ImageView(this);

Comment: I have done as your suggestion but it seems to not work. My ImageView is in a service unlike usual activities. So I'm struggling to resolve this problem but got no effect up to now.